# Trying to show an error for invalid email with regex but can't submit after changing reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

First off, I don't know if I worded this correctly. I'm new to react and trying to learn how to use hooks properly.

When I submit, I get an "invalid email" error whether it is or isn't valid.

I want to be able to show an invalid email error if it is an invalid email and prefer it to go away upon successful submission of a valid email.

I'll eventually be adding some conditions to the password too.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Link, useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';


const SignUp = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [name, setName] = useState("")
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("")
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
  const [error, setError] = useState("")
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("")


  const PostData = ()=> {
    // adding regex to validate proper email
    if(!/^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w.-]+)+[\w\-._~:/?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=.]+$/.test(email)){
      setError("Invalid email.")
      // added this to close out the whole process if there is an error
      return
    }
    fetch("/signup",{
      method:"post",
      headers:{
          "Content-Type":"application/json"
      },
      body:JSON.stringify({
          name,
          password,
          email,

      })
  }).then(res=>res.json())
    .then(data=>{
      if(data.error){
        setError(data.error)
      }
      else{
        setMessage(data.message)
        history.push('/signin')
      }
    }).catch(err=>{
      console.log(err)
    })
  }

  return(
    <div className="mycard">
      <div className="auth-card">
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <input 
        type="text"
        placeholder="name"
        value={name}
        onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input 
        type="text"
        placeholder="email"
        value={email}
        onChange={(e)=>setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input 
        type="text"
        placeholder="password"
        value={password}
        onChange={(e)=>setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button className="btn" onClick={()=>PostData()} >
          Sign Up
        </button>

        {/* Show Error or Message */}
        { error && <div style={{color: "red"}}> {error}</div> }
        { message && <div style={{color: "green"}}> {message}</div> }

        <h5>
          <Link to="/signup">Already have an account?</Link>
        </h5>

      </div>
    </div>
  )

}

export default SignUp
```

Comment: Your regex does not look to have anything to do with email validation - fix that first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you have does not validate an email address, but some sort of hyperlink. Use [a different regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript), or, even better, use `type="email"` on the input (inside a `<form>`) so that the browser validates it.

Another problem is that you're never clearing `error`, so if the email is invalid once on submission, the error won't go away. Clear `error` when the email field changes:

```
onChange={(e) => { setError(''); setEmail(e.target.value); }}
```

Comment: How do I say "I love you and thank you so much" in your language? Seriously, appreciate the feedback and you being nice about it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above, once you have your regex expression. you can validate the PostData function using the following.

```
const PostData = ()=> {
    regex="regex expression"
    //the regex expression for email validation goes here
    if(regex.test(email){
    setTimeOut(()=>{
       setError("Invalid email.")
    }, 3000) //using this will ensure the error message gets cleared after 3 seconds

      }
      else {
      fetch(...)
      }
    }
```